# Powershell - Add an extra column to a Converto-HTML

Tags: powershell

The following script works, it gets me a simple HTML table with
**Name** and **CreationTime** of the folders.  I would like to add a 3rd column with the title "Remove? Yes or No" and I am not sure how to do that.  I was also wondering if I can replace the NAME and CREATIONTIME for other names, but it is a lot of changes, I do not need that.

Could someone help me with this?
Thank you

```
$Header = @"
<style>
TABLE {border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-collapse: collapse;}
TH {text-align: left}
TD {width: 200px; text-align: left; border-width: 1px; padding: 3px; border-style: solid; border-color: black;}
TR:nth-child(even) {background-color: #BDBDBD;}
</style>
"@


$InitialFolder = "C:\WRA"
$ParentFolders = Get-ChildItem -Path $InitialFolder -Directory | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName

foreach ($SubFolder in $ParentFolders) {
    $path = Join-Path $SubFolder -ChildPath 'OwnerEmail.txt'
    
    $Contact = Get-Content -Path ($SubFolder + "\OwnerEmail.txt")
    $emailTime = (Get-Date).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")


# ================ Building HTML Report ================
    
$WRAHTMLReport = Get-ChildItem -Path $SubFolder -Directory | 
    #Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30))} |
    Select-Object Name, CreationTime |
    Sort-Object -Property CreationTime |
    ConvertTo-Html -Head $Header -PreContent "
            <h2>Current Nuix Case(s)</h2> 
            <body>
                Report was sent on $emailTime
                <br></br>
                The following table contains Nuix cases older than 30 days. When you have a moment, 
                please confirm if any of these cases can be removed by indicating which case(s) in the table. 
                Please reply to this email confirming removal of the cases noted on the table or if you have any questions regarding this report.
            <body> 
            <br></br> " -PostContent "
            <br></br>
                Thank you,"   |
    Tee-Object -FilePath "C:\APPS\WRA Send Report\WRAReport.html"
    Start-Sleep -s 1 
    Start "C:\APPS\WRA Send Report\WRAReport.html"
```

=========================
Another extra question:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.1#example-10--create-calculated-properties-for-each-inputobject) using `Select-Object`:

```
$WRAHTMLReport = Get-ChildItem -Path $SubFolder -Directory | 
Sort-Object -Property CreationTime |
Select-Object @{n='Insert Custom Name Here';e='Name'},
              @{n='Insert Custom Creation Date Here';e='CreationTime'},
              @{n='Remove? Yes or No';e={$null}} |
ConvertTo-Html -Head $Header -PreContent "
....
....
```

Other way, using a loop and casting [`[pscustomobject]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7.1):

```
$WRAHTMLReport = Get-ChildItem -Path $SubFolder -Directory | 
Sort-Object -Property CreationTime | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        'Insert Custom Name Here' = $_.Name
        'Insert Custom Creation Date Here' = $_.CreationTime
        'Remove? Yes or No' = $null
    }
} |
ConvertTo-Html -Head $Header -PreContent "
....
....
```

Comment: Thank you again Santiago!!  You have been helping me a lottttttttttttttt

Comment: Santiago,
One more question if you dont mind.  I uploaded a screenshot of the table.
In one of them, I added some color to the rows, but it is only visible when it exports the script as *.html (right color), but when it sends the $WRAHTMLReport in the -Body, it does not show the colors in the row (Left Picture).
I also added the initial <HEADER> style on the script.  I dont understand why it works when i export it as *.html, but it does not when it is on the body of the email.
Thank you so much again!

Comment: @Miguel `TR:nth-child(even) {background-color: #BDBDBD;}` is not compatible with Outlook clients unfortunately.

Comment: any other workaround?   it is not needed, but i am just curious

Comment: @Miguel for Outlook, if you want to create a zebra striped table you would need to use a loop and some old ass CSS. If you ask a new question I can try to show you.

Comment: Sorry for late response, it is ok, i dont think i need that CSS.  Thank you again Santiago!